# Google Sheet LARGE formula error "LARGE has no valid input data"

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

Trying to find out the Largest value in  column V when Year in A column matches with 2021 and Month matches with March (3).

Formula tried:

```
=ArrayFormula(large(If(AND(YEAR(A:A)="2021",MONTH(A:A)=3),V:V),1))
```

Above one giving me error :

```
LARGE has no valid input data.
```

There are entries which matches with year=2021 and month=3. can you guide me why it is giving me above error

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AAw0ie0RT5rY6hZ7RePDRDKUrikQBDX1YvQQaWWAG_Y/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LARGE(FILTER(V:V, YEAR(A:A)=2021, MONTH(A:A)=3), 1))
```

[image]